# Changebar with editable text propertes

Tags: pdfcomment, changebar

I would like to add changebar to the revised parts of my pdf but also I want to write a text on the change bars. I know two packages for changebar: 1- `cahngebar` package 2- `pdfcomment` package (with pdfsidelinecomment command).

But the problem is: `cahngebar` package does not accept text and in `pdfcomment` package (as far as I tried) I could not modify text properties of `pdfsidelinecomment`.

I would like to know if:

Is there a way to change the text properties in `pdfsidelinecomment` of `pdfcomment` package? I tried below commands but they did not work:

```
\begin{pdfsidelinecomment}[fontsize=10bp, fontcolor=red, font=TiRo]{test}
\begin{pdfsidelinecomment}{\textcolor{red}{test}}
```

When I run them in LaTeX, they does not return any error but they do nothing either! When I checked the output pdf with different pdf readers  the text of pdfsidelinecomment does not change, so it is not a reader issue.

OR

If it is not possible to do it in `pdfcomment` package, can you please guide me to create side line comments similar to the `pdfsidelinecomment` but with editable text.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I would like to edit font size, font colour and font type of the changebar text.

Answer (score 1):

What you try to achive is not possible with `pdfcomment`.

The `DA` key (default appearance string to be used in formatting the text) is **not** supported in PDF Line annotations, other than in PDF freetext annotations. See [PDF Reference 1.7](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) (p. 626 ff)

The `PDF` format does not support it, so `pdfcomment` can't either!

`font`, `fontsize` and `fontcolor` are not listed as possible options for `pdfsidelinecomment` or `pdflinecomment`.